# How to know what page on my site refers to a webpage on my site using GA?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm referring to like a referrer that comes from my own site (not external). Like page A refers to page B on mysite.com. Would "referral path" work? Cos I thought that is for external referrals only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Navigation Summary** in *Behavior* -> *Site Content* --> *All pages* and choosing *Navigation Summary*:

[image]

Or **Entrance Paths** in *Behavior* -> *Site Content* --> *Landing pages* and choosing *Entrance Paths*.